# Attach Entity "comment" to Entity "file"

Tags: 7, entities

Files (images) are uploaded within a content type with [plup](http://drupal.org/project/plup) and [plupload](http://drupal.org/project/plupload). These images are then displayed through a view.

**I would like to have a "commenting" functionality for each uploaded image**. I used [file_entity](http://drupal.org/project/file_entity) to have the images being considered as entities so that each of them can be treated individually within a node.

Drupal built-in comments can only be attached to nodes so I have used [reply](http://drupal.org/project/reply) to have the "commenting" functionality working as an entity.

Now I have a `hook_node_insert()` in which I loop through the images but how can I create a comment field for each of them?

```
function MY_MODULE_node_insert($node) {
    if($node->type=="my_content_type"){
        $pictures=$node->field_photos['und'];
        foreach ($pictures as $picture){
            // now what?
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to create one manually (a file with a comment), and output the resulting node (either look at it with a debugger, use drupal_debug or var_dump). Then you will see how it's supposed to be build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I don't see how I can add a file with a comment field (from the reply module) manually?

Comment: The Reply module page says "Such bundles can be attached to any fieldable entity by 'reply field'" - this suggests to me you need to add a field of type 'Reply Field' to your file entity. Once you have that you would be able to add comments using the Reply module (but I may be wrong, haven't used it myself)

Comment: Indeed! I already have the field of type "Reply" in my `field_config_instance` but if I follow instructions as stated  there http://drupal.org/node/1228878#comment-4827038. Problem is that when I run `field_create_instance($field_instance)`, I have an error: `FieldException: Attempt to create an instance of field field_reply_comment on bundle image that already has an instance of that field`.

Comment: When you call `field_create_instance` you are adding a **field** to the content type. You have already done this, no need to do it again ! When you say you want to add a comment, what you want to add is a **value** for that field. And when I said "create one manually" I meant using the User Interface. If that's not possible then I don't see the point of the Reply module !

Comment: No, I want to create a field "comment" for each file uploaded; the value of this field will be inserted when a user creates a comment.

Comment: Yes, fields are added only once per content type - not once per node. The problem is elsewhere.

Comment: So that means I can't have several fields "comment" on entity type "file"?

Comment: Now I think that I shouldn't use a `hook_node_insert()` but rather a `hook_node_view()` (even if I don't know yet what code to include) but if I use the view hook, can I eventually catch it field from views?